# Is there a method that executes after Observable's onSuccess() or onError()?

Tags: android, rx-java

It is very often that I need to show some loading behavior in my app and I want to dismiss it once the work is done - **no matter if the result of the work is success or an error**. Therefore, I end up with code like that:

```
addDisposable(router.launchHomepage()                            
    .compose(loadingView.show()))
    .subscribe(
        { loadingView.dismiss() },
        { loadingView.dismiss() }
    )
)
```

Is there a way to dismiss the loading view in a single method? Like `onComplete()` but called no matter if the result is success or error?

Comment: use you Rxjava1 or Rxjava2?

Comment: Using RxJava2...

Comment: Ok. I will give you my source code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create class

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import io.reactivex.FlowableTransformer;
import io.reactivex.ObservableTransformer;
import io.reactivex.SingleTransformer;
import io.reactivex.functions.Action;
import io.reactivex.functions.Consumer;

public class RxShowDialogUtil {

private ProgressDialog dialog;
private final Context context;

private final Consumer SUBSCRIBE_ACTION = new Consumer() {
    @Override
    public void accept(@NonNull Object o) throws Exception {
        if (dialog != null && !dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.show();
        }
    }
};

private final Action UN_SUBSCRIBE_ACTION = new Action() {
    @Override
    public void run() throws Exception {
        if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        dialog = null;
    }
};

private RxShowDialogUtil(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public static RxShowDialogUtil createInstance(Context context) {
    return new RxShowDialogUtil(context);
}

public static RxShowDialogUtil createInstance(Fragment fragment) {
    return new RxShowDialogUtil(fragment.getActivity());
}

public <T> SingleTransformer<T, T> applyDialogForSingle() {
    createDialog(context);
    return upstream -> upstream.doOnSubscribe(SUBSCRIBE_ACTION).doFinally(UN_SUBSCRIBE_ACTION);
}

public <T> ObservableTransformer<T, T> applyDialogForObservable() {
    createDialog(context);
    return upstream -> upstream.doOnSubscribe(SUBSCRIBE_ACTION).doFinally(UN_SUBSCRIBE_ACTION);
}

public <T>FlowableTransformer<T,T> applyDialogForFlowable(){
    createDialog(context);
    return upstream -> upstream.doOnSubscribe(SUBSCRIBE_ACTION).doFinally(UN_SUBSCRIBE_ACTION);
}

private Dialog createDialog(final Context context) {
    if (dialog == null) {
        dialog = DialogUtils.getInstance().getProgressDialog(context);
    }
    return dialog;
}
}
```

And Use

```
addDisposable(router.launchHomepage()                            
.compose(RxShowDialogUtil.createInstance(this).applyDialogForObservable())
.subscribe(
    { },
    { }
)
)
```

Comment: Awesome! I understood the complete answer that you gave but the ```doFinally()``` is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks